# How can I get the current user who purchased a product from the onOrderComplete event?

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-craftcommerce

I have a plugin that is listening to the `onOrderComplete` event within commerce. I am able to get the email address like this:

```
craft()->on('commerce_orders.onOrderComplete', function (Event $event) {
    $event->params['order']->email;  // name@email.com

});
```

I can see the Id in the log, but since I'm in the order class, I'm not sure how to get to it. I can see `customerId`:

```
$event->params['order']->customerId; // 3
```

But I've noticed the `customerId` and the `userId` are different. I need to be able to get the logged in `userId` vs. the `customerId`

When I try getting just the id, I get the product id back (Which is what I would expect).

```
$event->params['order']->id;  // 123
```

To relate to the twig side it would be something like this (obviously won't work):

```
$event->params['order']['currentUser']->id;  // 12
```

Here is a part of the log:

```
...
[_attributes:Craft\BaseModel:private] => Array
(
    [enabled] => 1
    [archived] => 0
    [locale] => en_us
    [localeEnabled] => 1
    [itemTotal] => 375
    [baseDiscount] => 0
    [baseShippingCost] => 0
    [totalPrice] => 375
    [totalPaid] => 375.00
    [billingAddressId] => 122
    [shippingAddressId] => 123
    [paymentMethodId] => 1
    [customerId] => 3
    [id] => 12   //  <-- This guy right here
    [orderStatusId] => 1
...
```

Comment: Are all of your orders going to be with logged in users or do you have a guest checkout workflow?

Comment: They will always be logged in. You must have an account on my site in order to purchase a product.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something isn't [currentUser](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/global-variables#currentUser) what you're looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is happening from the `onOrderComplete` event, the easiest way to get the currently logged in user is with [UserSessionService::getUser()](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/UserSessionService#getUser-detail):

```php
$user = craft()->userSession->getUser();
```

Alternatively, if you want to go through the actual Commerce_OrderModel that was passed as a parameter on the event, you can do this:

```php
$user = $event->params['order']->getCustomer()->getUser();
```

Either way, it’s a good idea to verify that `$user` gets set to something, just in case:

```php
if ($user) {
    // ...
}
```